# Retrieving Google Map data into Matlab to plot points

Tags: google-maps, web-mapping, google, matlab

First of all, I hope this question isn't too basic, obvious or inappropriate for this forum. I'm very new to using map data. I'm working on a project on more accurate map routing using Matlab.

My question is:

I'm getting data from Google Map but how can I retrieve it to Matlab and plotting it?

Comment: How are you getting the data from a google map? Is it a kml file? A quick google search turned up this function to read in kml files into MATLAB, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13026-readkml.

Comment: Can I retrieve it directly from the google map using html??
And how to use this file? I never use this before!

Comment: Not that I'm aware (perhaps you can scrape it, I'm not sure offhand though). This other question (and the answers) may be helpful as well, [Generate a kml file from Google results](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/3448/751). What data are you trying to get from the google map?

Comment: I only want data that can read on the matlab program and I can plot and route the data I want. Lastly export to kml file.

Comment: So you want the begin and end coordinates for some route I suppose (or do you want the entire line for a route)? "I only want data that can read on the matlab program" doesn't make any sense, what data **do you specifically want**. I suspect whatever you want is possible, but I have no idea if a MATLAB program is already written to get it. Take a look at this program written for [Stata](http://phlib.kku.ac.th/StataJournalOnline/sj11-1.pdf#page=114) and see if that is similar to the information you would like to get for your project.

Comment: Scrape the idea I said previously! After I tried out with a GPS, I found out that the data is in kml format. How can I read it on the MATLAB?

Comment: Hopefully with that same function I linked to previously can do that, http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13026-readkml. Just do an internet search for kml and MATLAB, I suspect many custom user functions exist.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info!! I was unsure what to do at first, but really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Google T&C doesnt allow to read the satellite images using any external tools. It doesnt matter if you do it with or without google's knowledge. Its illegal. you can take a screenshot of the satellite maps from browser but then its an digital image not a **Geospatial** data. you wont have any spatial information from it.
KML/KMZ gives you data in **vector** format

Answer (score 1):

You can use the google maps API, then you just need to convert the JSON output to something you can conveniently work with.

Note however, that the terms of google specifically mention that you are only allowed to use this when you want to present the result as a google map!